# Delete all rows in sqlite database not working - iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

Im having an issue deleting all the rows in a sqlite table I created, I can delete from this table based on a condition, (name, date etc) however when I try to delete all the contents in the table it fails: Here is what I've tried:

```
-(void) deleteFromDB{
    NSLog(@"delete from DB method being called");

    NSString * deleteQuery = @"DELETE * FROM CLUB";
    [self deleteData:deleteQuery];
}

-(void)deleteData:(NSString *)deleteQuery{
    char *error;
    NSLog(@"Enter deleteData");

    if (sqlite3_exec(clubDB, [deleteQuery UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error)==SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"CLUB info deleted");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Failed");
       NSLog(@"Failed with %s", error);

    }
}
```

I get an output of failed.

```
NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }
```

cant delete is never printed

The error message is:

```
X”¿
```

*Update****
clubDB is of type sqlite3 (declared in .h as sqlite3*clubDB

error string updated above

**Update2*******

Here is the code for opeing/creating the database:

```
-(void) createOrOpenDB{
NSArray * path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * docPath = [path objectAtIndex:0];

dbPathString = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"club.db"];
NSLog(@"path = %@",dbPathString);

char*error;

NSFileManager*fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPathString]){

    const char * dbPath = [dbPathString UTF8String];

    //create db here
    if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &clubDB)==SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"success");
        const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CLUB (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, SUBJECT TEXT)";
        sqlite3_exec(clubDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error);
        sqlite3_close(clubDB);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You pass in a buffer for the error message, what does the buffer say?

Comment: You didn't try printing the error message???

Comment: Here's a hint: `NSLog(@"Failed with %s", error)`.

Comment: the error message is : Failed with X”¿

Comment: Update your code to show how you use the error string. What type is clubDB, is it a valid handle?

Comment: please see above for the update

Comment: Try setting `char *error = NULL;`.

Comment: I've never seen SQLite fail to give a good error message when it fails.  But of course it may not have "failed".  You need to capture the return code and print it.

Comment: (Wherever you copied that SQLite example from was not a particularly good source.)

Comment: @ott-- the error message that is returned is (null)

Comment: @HotLicks- how would I return the return code? the example I used is working mostly apart from what I want (deleting all from CLUB)

Comment: `sqlite_exec()` should return 0 on success, can you check that instead of `SQLITE_OK`?

Comment: @HotLicks- strangley enough, when i got into /library/application support/iPhone Simulator and then the relevant app, the database is not in the documents folder (where it should be), however it is working...have you ever come across this?

Comment: @ott-- unfortunately it says "sqlite_exec() is invalid in C99" and the application fails, not too sure what that means

Comment: Instead of simply testing the return code of sqlite3_exec (and effectively throwing it away if not "OK"), assign it to an int, and then test the int.  If you get a "bad" value, print it.

Comment: @ott-- the NSLog "CLUB info deleted is performed" - however it hasnt been removed from the DB

Comment: Where is the DB you're actually opening?  Print out the path you use in the SQLite open operation.

Comment: The table should still be there, only all rows should be deleted.

Comment: Sorry hot licks its there, i was looking at an old version in its path

Comment: @ott-- Yes I understand but the information is still within the rows, it hasnt been deleted.

Comment: @HotLicks- the error number is 21

Comment: `#define SQLITE_MISUSE      21   /* Library used incorrectly */` - got feeling 21 is a bad year.

Comment: @ott-- hmmmm interesting...ive no idea, its been a method that has not left me down till now.

Comment: We need more, like opening the database.

Comment: @ott-- updated above!

Comment: Don't close the DB when you want to do other actions later.

Answer (score 3):

Your delete statement isn't valid SQL. To delete everything from CLUB it would be:

```
delete from CLUB
```

You don't need the star as it obviously affects the whole record.

Comment: Thanks for the reply however it is still failing